# Using Grunt with Source Control (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, gruntjs

My source control does not allow me to write to files unless they're checked out in Visual Studio. When I run grunt, my minification process fails b/c it doesn't have acccess to the output file (the bundled/minified file). I have to check the file out manually whenever I build.

How can I avoid this? Seems a little disruptive. I see two options:

1. Don't have developers use Grunt since bundling/minifcation is only for production anyway. Let the build team use Grunt instead when they do production deployments.
2. Let developers use Grunt, but have Visual Studio / TFS automatically perform a checkout of the target minified javascript/css files so it can write to them.

How are others handling this? What is the right way to use Grunt like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might be using server workspaces. In TFS2012 you can change the project to use local workspaces. One of the benefits is it removes the readonly flags from files and you can edit files outside of VS.

Comment: Yes that's right - server workspaces. Are there any other differences to be cognizant of?

Comment: Take a look here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx